# Problem with building Maven project - not including libraries into jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a problem with building project. After last changes size of my package myproject-api.jar is about 90k, before it was about 80mb. I can't figure out was is the cause, I changed only version from 4.5.0-SNAPHOT to 4.5.0. Before changes in myproject-api.jar there was all dependencies, now there are only classes from project. I need to have one jar - myproject-api.jar with all dependencies which will be able to start as a single spring boot jar, like before.

Main pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>myproject-database</module>
        <module>myproject-model</module>
        <module>myproject-api</module>
        <module>myproject-commons</module>
        <module>myproject-service</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- version properties -->
        <myproject_version>4.5.0-SNAPSHOT</myproject_version>
        <spring_version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring_version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- myproject-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>myproject-database</artifactId>
                <version>${myproject_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>myproject-model</artifactId>
                <version>${myproject_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>myproject-commons</artifactId>
                <version>${myproject_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
                <version>${myproject_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Mail + Thymeleaf -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                <version>${spring_version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.25</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Java EE-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Wymagane przez testowy chat w JS - tymczasowo! -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.44</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Firebird -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Lombok -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Log -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.30</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- JSON -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20180813</version>
                <!--<version>20190722</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <!-- Swagger -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- JUnit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Jasper Report -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- GOOGLE -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.28.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- FACEBOOK -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
                <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

myproject-commons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myproject-commons</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

myproject-database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myproject-database</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

myproject-model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myproject-model</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-database</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

myproject-service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- myproject-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-database</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail + Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ====== -->
        <!-- Wymagane przez testowy chat w JS - tymczasowo! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ========= -->
        <!-- Firebird -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper Report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GOOGLE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FACEBOOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputFile>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/version.properties
                            </outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

myproject-api:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myproject-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- myproject-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-database</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail + Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ====== -->

        <!-- Wymagane przez testowy chat w JS - tymczasowo! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ========= -->

        <!-- Firebird -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper Report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GOOGLE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FACEBOOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Update 1:

I added version of plugins, but it didn't help.

myproject-commons, myproject-database:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

myproject-api:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring_version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you add a version to plugin?

Comment: just for test purpose: plz add "repackage" plugin execution as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) ..to your runnable project, but strange, that `SNAPSHOT->RELEASE` changed the behavior... (you are talking of your project.version?)

Comment: ...and generally i encountered never such issues/found it a good practice: to inherit (parent) poms from spring-boot-starter-parent. (as another test, plz: (also) add maven plugin (no/default executions)

Comment: ..to parent pom.

Comment: @xerx593: adding "repackage" plugin execution helped, thanks for help!

Comment: ..if i'd understand it better, i'd come up with an answer (btw. you can answer(&accept) your own question;), but glad to help & welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin to wrap up the dependencies in the compiled jar.